# VBA: Displaying Grid of Checkbox on VBA UserForm Frame

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I am stuck with creating checkbox like a grid of checkbox. Basically I have a list of sheets to be created, and the approach is that, when I check the checkbox corresponding sheets should be create in Active Workbook. I am done with it, but I am stuck with create grid of checkboxs as I want to utilize vacant space in my form.

For instance,

```
Checkbox1             Checkbox2  
Checkbox3             Checkbox4
```

Below is my code which I have coded.

```
For Each varItem In InfantDataQuerySheets
    checkboxInc = checkboxInc + 1
    Set chkbox = SelectDataQuerySheet.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox" &      checkboxInc, True)
    With chkbox
        .Left = 10
        .Top = (checkboxInc - 1) * (chkbox.Height + 3)
        .Caption = varItem
    End With
Next varItem
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For Each varItem In InfantDataQuerySheets
    checkboxInc = checkboxInc + 1
    Set chkbox = SelectDataQuerySheet.Controls.Add( _
                  "Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox" &  checkboxInc, True)

    With chkbox
        .Left = IIf(checkboxInc Mod 2 = 1, 10, 40) 'edited
        .Top = Application.Floor((checkboxInc - 1)/2, 1) * (chkbox.Height + 3)
        .Caption = varItem
    End With

Next varItem
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for immediate reply, added your code and it worked. But did some changes replaced the MOD Function which you are using as

Comment: Thanks Tim for your helpful reply

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each varItem In InfantDataQuerySheets
    checkboxInc = checkboxInc + 1
    Set chkbox = SelectDataQuerySheet.Controls.Add( _
                  "Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox" &  checkboxInc, True)

    With chkbox
        .Left = IIf((checkboxInc - (2 * (checkboxInc \ 2))) = 1, 10, 40)
        .Top = Application.Floor((checkboxInc - 1)/2, 1) * (chkbox.Height + 3)
        .Caption = varItem
    End With

Next varItem
```

Added Mod formula as IIF was giving error **Need Expression**